# How using sp_executesql with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote a query:

```
DECLARE @Col_Select NVARCHAR(10);
SET @Col_Select = N'[od.orderID]';

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @Query = N'SELECT quantity, COUNT(o.orderID) FROM orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN [order details] od ON o.orderid = @Col_Select group by od.quantity';

EXEC sp_executesql @Query,@Col_Select
```

What is wrong with my query?

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'od.orderI)SELECT quantity,COUNT(o.orderID)
>   FROM orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN [order details'.

Comment: can you also share the code of [sp_executesql] ?

Comment: @Dorin See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are building a dynamic query where the fields change, this can't be done by normal parameters.  You'll have to use the parameter to build up the string of the query - be *very* careful if you can supply @Col_Select from user input to avoid SQL Injection attacks!

```
SET @Query=N'SELECT quantity,COUNT(o.orderID) FROM orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN [order details] od ON o.orderid = ' + @Col_Select + ' group by od.quantity';
```